# Firebase: Get child of snapshot.val() object

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to get an object of the first matching child using Firebase's admin SDK. So far I was able to get an object inside a parent object:

```
{ -LVOBaJXoai9n1mYrs3F: { created: 1546610959716, displayEnterpriseNumber: "BE 0479.312.137", email: "anthony.magnus@gmail.com", enterpriseNumber: "479312137" } }
```

but I want

```
{ created: 1546610959716, email: "john.doe@gmail.com", token: '51234', isActive: true }
```

**Code**

In a firebase function, I have the following code:

```
try {
   const token = req.body.token;
   const couponSnapshot = await admin.database().ref(`coupons`).orderByChild('token').equalTo(token).limitToFirst(1).once('value');
   const coupon = couponSnapshot.val();

   console.log(coupon) //{-LVOBaJXoai9n1mYrs3F: {…}} Object in Object...

} catch(error) {
   //error handling
}
```

How can I get the child object from the parent object?

I tried to loop over the couponSnapshot and attach the child value to the coupon variable but I'm getting an error.

```
const couponSnapshot = await admin.database().ref(`coupons`).orderByChild('token').equalTo(token).limitToFirst(1).once('value');

let coupon = {};

couponSnapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
  coupon = childSnapshot.val();
});

console.log(coupon.email);
```

The error:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '(childSnapshot: DataSnapshot) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(
a: DataSnapshot) => boolean'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

Property 'email' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've told TypeScript that you want to strongly type coupon to be an empty object, and only an empty object.  You're later telling it to access a property on the object `email` that doesn't exist in an empty object.  That's why you're coming up with the error: `Property 'email' does not exist on type '{}'.`

You should not provide any typing hints at all.  Simply `let email;` with no default assignment if you want it to be of type `any`, which lets you access arbitrary properties on the object.  Of course, you may also need to check if it's defined before reaching into it, as that would be an error as well.

Comment: You might want to clarify where specifically you're seeing other errors, as I copy and pasted your code and couldn't reproduce anything else.

Comment: Hmm, Well I solved the first error `Argument of type '(childSnapshot: DataSnapshot) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(
a: DataSnapshot) => boolean'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.` by adding `return true;` in the forEach loop.

Comment: OK, that's because the function passed to forEach is expected to return true or false depending on whether or not you want to continue to the next child in the list.